# Pass Client IP from AWS ELB to HA Proxy

Tags: haproxy, amazon-elb, x-forwarded-for

We have a issue in our application where the client IP is not getting passed to the App servers in the following setup.

USER---------> AWS ELB -----------> HAPROXY -----------> Application server(apache)

Our ELB is using TCP listeners and we have enabled Proxy protocol header. 
In HA proxy we have added "option forwardfor" in the haproxy.cfg

We are able to get the client IP for http requests through "x-forwarded-for" header, but not for https.

Appreciate any help in identifying what is the missing part in our setup.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Amazon ELB resets the TCP parameters when used as TCP listener.  You can enable proxy protocol on ELB to retain these parameters:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html

Once done, you can modify haproxy to understand proxy protocol:
https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#5.2-send-proxy